# Next JS, Submit Function Not Triggered on Form Field Validation Error

Tags: reactjs, forms, validation, next.js, react-hook-form

I have this component with one problem: when there is a mistake in one of the form fields, the 'onSubmit' function does not execute or get called:

```
"use client";
import * as z from "zod";
import axios from "axios";
import { useState, useRef, useEffect } from "react";
import { zodResolver } from "@hookform/resolvers/zod";
import { useForm } from "react-hook-form";
import toast from "react-hot-toast";

import { CaretSortIcon } from "@/components/SVGs";
import { Input } from "@/components/ui/input";
import { Button } from "@/components/ui/button";
import {
  Form,
  FormControl,
  FormDescription,
  FormField,
  FormItem,
  FormLabel,
  FormMessage,
} from "@/components/ui/form";
import {
  Command,
  CommandEmpty,
  CommandGroup,
  CommandInput,
  CommandItem,
} from "@/components/ui/command";
import {
  Popover,
  PopoverContent,
  PopoverTrigger,
} from "@/components/ui/popover";
import { Customer } from "@/types";
import { cn } from "@/lib/utils";
import { CheckIcon } from "lucide-react";
import { countrys } from "@/components/countries";
import { Textarea } from "@/components/ui/textarea";
import useShoppingCart from "@/hooks/useShoppingCart";
import { Checkbox } from "@/components/ui/checkbox";

const formSchema = z.object({
  billing_first_name: z
    .string()
    .min(2, { message: "Ce champ est obligatoire" }),
  billing_last_name: z.string().min(2, { message: "Ce champ est obligatoire" }),
  billing_company: z.string().optional(),
  billing_address_1: z.string().min(5, { message: "Ce champ est obligatoire" }),
  billing_address_2: z.string().optional(),
  billing_city: z.string().min(2, { message: "Ce champ est obligatoire" }),
  billing_postcode: z.string().min(3, { message: "Ce champ est obligatoire" }),
  billing_country: z.string().min(2, { message: "Ce champ est obligatoire" }),
  billing_email: z
    .string()
    .email({ message: "adresse e-mail invalide" })
    .min(3, { message: "Ce champ est obligatoire" }),
  billing_phone: z.string().min(2, { message: "Ce champ est obligatoire" }),

  shipping_first_name: z
    .string()
    .min(2, { message: "Ce champ est obligatoire" }),
  shipping_last_name: z
    .string()
    .min(2, { message: "Ce champ est obligatoire" }),
  shipping_company: z.string().optional(),
  shipping_address_1: z
    .string()
    .min(5, { message: "Ce champ est obligatoire" }),
  shipping_address_2: z.string().optional(),
  shipping_city: z.string().min(2, { message: "Ce champ est obligatoire" }),
  shipping_postcode: z.string().min(3, { message: "Ce champ est obligatoire" }),
  shipping_country: z.string().min(2, { message: "Ce champ est obligatoire" }),

  notes: z.string().optional(),
});

type CheckoutValues = z.infer<typeof formSchema>;

interface CheckoutProps {
  initialData: Customer;
}

const CheckoutForm: React.FC<CheckoutProps> = ({ initialData }) => {
  const hiddenButtonRef = useRef<HTMLButtonElement | null>(null);
  const [open_1, setOpen_1] = useState(false);
  const [open_2, setOpen_2] = useState(false);
  const [show, setShow] = useState(false);

  const items = useShoppingCart((state) => state.items);
  const shipping_metod = useShoppingCart((state) => state.shipping_method);
  const tva_cost = useShoppingCart((state) => state.tva_cost);
  const tva_rates = useShoppingCart((state) => state.tva_rates);

  const submit = useShoppingCart((state) => state.submitCheckout);
  const setSubmit = useShoppingCart((state) => state.setSubmitCheckout);
  const submitSamuray = useShoppingCart((state) => state.submit);
  const setSubmitSamuray = useShoppingCart((state) => state.setSubmit);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (hiddenButtonRef.current && submit === true) {
      hiddenButtonRef.current.click();
    }
  }, [submit]);

  const handleCheckboxChange = () => {
    setShow(!show);
  };

  let updatedDefaultValues = {
    billing_first_name: "",
    billing_last_name: "",
    billing_company: "",
    billing_address_1: "",
    billing_address_2: "",
    billing_city: "",
    billing_postcode: "",
    billing_country: "",
    billing_email: "",
    billing_phone: "",

    shipping_first_name: "",
    shipping_last_name: "",
    shipping_company: "",
    shipping_address_1: "",
    shipping_address_2: "",
    shipping_city: "",
    shipping_postcode: "",
    shipping_country: "",
    notes: "",
  };

  const form = useForm<CheckoutValues>({
    resolver: zodResolver(formSchema),
    defaultValues: updatedDefaultValues,
  });

  useEffect(() => {
    // eslint-disable-next-line
    updatedDefaultValues = initialData
      ? {
          // Billing information
          billing_first_name: initialData.billing.first_name,
          billing_last_name: initialData.billing.last_name,
          billing_company: initialData.billing.company,
          billing_address_1: initialData.billing.address_1,
          billing_address_2: initialData.billing.address_2,
          billing_city: initialData.billing.city,
          billing_postcode: initialData.billing.postcode,
          billing_country: initialData.billing.country,
          billing_email: initialData.billing.email,
          billing_phone: initialData.billing.phone,

          // Shipping information
          shipping_first_name: show
            ? initialData.shipping.first_name
            : initialData.billing.first_name,
          shipping_last_name: show
            ? initialData.shipping.last_name
            : initialData.billing.last_name,
          shipping_company: show
            ? initialData.shipping.company
            : initialData.billing.company,
          shipping_address_1: show
            ? initialData.shipping.address_1
            : initialData.billing.address_1,
          shipping_address_2: show
            ? initialData.shipping.address_2
            : initialData.shipping.address_2,
          shipping_city: show
            ? initialData.shipping.city
            : initialData.billing.city,
          shipping_postcode: show
            ? initialData.shipping.postcode
            : initialData.billing.postcode,
          shipping_country: show
            ? initialData.shipping.country
            : initialData.billing.country,
          notes: "",
        }
      : {
          billing_first_name: "",
          billing_last_name: "",
          billing_company: "",
          billing_address_1: "",
          billing_address_2: "",
          billing_city: "",
          billing_postcode: "",
          billing_country: "",
          billing_email: "",
          billing_phone: "",

          shipping_first_name: "",
          shipping_last_name: "",
          shipping_company: "",
          shipping_address_1: "",
          shipping_address_2: "",
          shipping_city: "",
          shipping_postcode: "",
          shipping_country: "",
          notes: "",
        };
    // console.log(
    //   `show: ${show}: ` + JSON.stringify(updatedDefaultValues, null, 4)
    // );
    form.reset(updatedDefaultValues);
  }, [show, initialData]);

  const onSubmit = async (data: CheckoutValues) => {
    try {
      // alert(JSON.stringify(data, null, 4));
      const response = await axios.post("/api/payment", {
        products: items,
        checkout: data,
        shipping_metod: shipping_metod,
        tva_rates: tva_rates,
        tva_cost: tva_cost,
      });
      window.location = response.data.url;
      setSubmit(false);
    } catch (error: any) {
      toast.error(error.response?.data?.error || "An error occurred.");
    } finally {
      setSubmit(false);
    }
  };

  return (
    <>
      <Form {...form}>
        <form
          onSubmit={form.handleSubmit(onSubmit)}
          className="flex flex-col text-left w-full gap-y-8"
        >
          <div className="bg-white shadow-md flex flex-col text-left w-full gap-y-6 p-[24px_22px] border border-solid border-[#f5f4f7] rounded-lg">
            <h4 className="text-black font-medium text-[16px] leading-[100%] tracking-[-0.04em] mb-[26px]">
              Détails de facturation.
            </h4>

            <div className="w-full grid-cols-1 grid lg:grid-cols-2 gap-8">
              {/* first Name */}
              <FormField
                control={form.control}
                name="billing_first_name"
                render={({ field }) => (
                  <FormItem>
                    <FormLabel>Prénom*</FormLabel>
                    <FormControl>
                      <Input
                        disabled={submit ? true : false}
                        placeholder="Entrez votre prénom..."
                        {...field}
                        type="text"
                        className="bg-[#f1f1f1] max-w-[calc(100%-12px)] mx-[auto] focus-visible:outline-[#dfb572]"
                      />
                    </FormControl>
                    <FormMessage className="text-[#ea400e] text-[10px] p-[5px_0px_0px] !m-0" />
                  </FormItem>
                )}
              />

              {/* last Name */}
              <FormField
                control={form.control}
                name="billing_last_name"
                render={({ field }) => (
                  <FormItem>
                    <FormLabel>Nom de famille*</FormLabel>
                    <FormControl>
                      <Input
                        disabled={submit ? true : false}
                        placeholder="Entrez votre nom de famille..."
                        {...field}
                        type="text"
                        className="bg-[#f1f1f1] max-w-[calc(100%-12px)] mx-[auto] focus-visible:outline-[#dfb572]"
                      />
                    </FormControl>
                    <FormMessage className="text-[#ea400e] text-[10px] p-[5px_0px_0px] !m-0" />
                  </FormItem>
                )}
              />
            </div>

            {/* Company name (optional) */}
            <FormField
              control={form.control}
              name="billing_company"
              render={({ field }) => (
                <FormItem>
                  <FormLabel>Nom de l&apos;entreprise (facultatif)</FormLabel>
                  <FormControl>
                    <Input
                      disabled={submit ? true : false}
                      placeholder=""
                      {...field}
                      type="text"
                      className="bg-[#f1f1f1] max-w-[calc(100%-12px)] mx-[auto] focus-visible:outline-[#dfb572]"
                    />
                  </FormControl>
                  <FormMessage className="text-[#ea400e] text-[10px] p-[5px_0px_0px] !m-0" />
                </FormItem>
              )}
            />

            {/* Country */}
            <FormField
              control={form.control}
              name="billing_country"
              render={({ field }) => (
                <FormItem className="flex flex-col ">
                  <FormLabel>Pays / Région *</FormLabel>
                  <Popover open={open_1} onOpenChange={setOpen_1}>
                    <PopoverTrigger asChild>
                      <FormControl>
                        <Button
                          disabled={submit ? true : false}
                          variant="outline"
                          role="combobox"
                          aria-expanded={open_1}
                          className={cn(
                            "w-[100%] justify-between bg-[#f1f1f1] max-w-[calc(100%-12px)] mx-[auto] focus-visible:outline-[#dfb572]",
                            !field.value && "text-muted-foreground"
                          )}
                        >
                          {field.value
                            ? countrys.find(
                                (country) => country.value === field.value
                              )?.label
                            : "Sélectionner un pays / une région..."}
                          <CaretSortIcon />
                        </Button>
                      </FormControl>
                    </PopoverTrigger>
                    <PopoverContent className="w-[200px] max-h-96 overflow-y-auto p-0 relative">
                      <Command>
                        <CommandInput
                          placeholder="Search country..."
                          className="h-9"
                        />
                        <CommandEmpty>No country found.</CommandEmpty>
                        <CommandGroup>
                          {countrys.map((country) => (
                            <CommandItem
                              value={country.label}
                              key={country.value}
                              onSelect={() => {
                                form.setValue("billing_country", country.value);
                                setOpen_1(false);
                              }}
                            >
                              {country.label}
                              <CheckIcon
                                className={cn(
                                  "ml-auto h-4 w-4",
                                  country.value === field.value
                                    ? "opacity-100"
                                    : "opacity-0"
                                )}
                              />
                            </CommandItem>
                          ))}
                        </CommandGroup>
                      </Command>
                    </PopoverContent>
                  </Popover>

                  <FormMessage className="text-[#ea400e] text-[10px] p-[5px_0px_0px] !m-0" />
                </FormItem>
              )}
            />

            {/* Town / City * */}
            <FormField
              control={form.control}
              name="billing_city"
              render={({ field }) => (
                <FormItem>
                  <FormLabel>Ville *</FormLabel>
                  <FormControl>
                    <Input
                      disabled={submit ? true : false}
                      placeholder="Entrez votre ville"
                      {...field}
                      type="text"
                      className="bg-[#f1f1f1] max-w-[calc(100%-12px)] mx-[auto] focus-visible:outline-[#dfb572]"
                    />
                  </FormControl>
                  <FormMessage className="text-[#ea400e] text-[10px] p-[5px_0px_0px] !m-0" />
                </FormItem>
              )}
            />

            {/* Street address */}
            <FormField
              control={form.control}
              name="billing_address_1"
              render={({ field }) => (
                <FormItem>
                  <FormLabel>Adresse postale *</FormLabel>
                  <FormControl>
                    <Input
                      disabled={submit ? true : false}
                      placeholder="Numéro de maison et nom de la rue"
                      {...field}
                      type="text"
                      className="bg-[#f1f1f1] max-w-[calc(100%-12px)] mx-[auto] focus-visible:outline-[#dfb572]"
                    />
                  </FormControl>
                  <FormMessage className="text-[#ea400e] text-[10px] p-[5px_0px_0px] !m-0" />
                </FormItem>
              )}
            />

            {/* Street address */}
            <FormField
              control={form.control}
              name="billing_address_2"
              render={({ field }) => (
                <FormItem>
                  {/* <FormLabel>Street address *</FormLabel> */}
                  <FormControl>
                    <Input
                      disabled={submit ? true : false}
                      placeholder="Appartement, suite, unité, etc. (facultatif)"
                      {...field}
                      type="text"
                      className="bg-[#f1f1f1] max-w-[calc(100%-12px)] mx-[auto] focus-visible:outline-[#dfb572]"
                    />
                  </FormControl>
                  <FormMessage className="text-[#ea400e] text-[10px] p-[5px_0px_0px] !m-0" />
                </FormItem>
              )}
            />

            {/* Postcode / ZIP * */}
            <FormField
              control={form.control}
              name="billing_postcode"
              render={({ field }) => (
                <FormItem>
                  <FormLabel>Code postal / ZIP *</FormLabel>
                  <FormControl>
                    <Input
                      disabled={submit ? true : false}
                      placeholder="Entrez la code postal de votre ville"
                      {...field}
                      type="text"
                      className="bg-[#f1f1f1] max-w-[calc(100%-12px)] mx-[auto] focus-visible:outline-[#dfb572]"
                    />
                  </FormControl>
                  <FormMessage className="text-[#ea400e] text-[10px] p-[5px_0px_0px] !m-0" />
                </FormItem>
              )}
            />

            {/* Phone */}
            <FormField
              control={form.control}
              name="billing_phone"
              render={({ field }) => (
                <FormItem>
                  <FormLabel>Téléphone *</FormLabel>
                  <FormControl>
                    <Input
                      disabled={submit ? true : false}
                      placeholder="Entrez votre téléphone"
                      {...field}
                      type="text"
                      className="bg-[#f1f1f1] max-w-[calc(100%-12px)] mx-[auto] focus-visible:outline-[#dfb572]"
                    />
                  </FormControl>
                  <FormMessage className="text-[#ea400e] text-[10px] p-[5px_0px_0px] !m-0" />
                </FormItem>
              )}
            />

            {/* Email address */}
            <FormField
              control={form.control}
              name="billing_email"
              render={({ field }) => (
                <FormItem>
                  <FormLabel>Adresse e-mail *</FormLabel>
                  <FormControl>
                    <Input
                      disabled={submit ? true : false}
                      placeholder="Entrez votre adresse e-mail"
                      {...field}
                      type="email"
                      className="bg-[#f1f1f1] max-w-[calc(100%-12px)] mx-[auto] focus-visible:outline-[#dfb572]"
                    />
                  </FormControl>
                  <FormMessage className="text-[#ea400e] text-[10px] p-[5px_0px_0px] !m-0" />
                </FormItem>
              )}
            />
          </div>

          <Button type="submit" className={"hidden"} ref={hiddenButtonRef}>
            Continuer vers le paiement
          </Button>
        </form>
      </Form>
    </>
  );
};`

export default CheckoutForm;
```

i expecting that when the form get submit the onSubmit will be call it and if there is any error on the form will do 'setSubmit(false)' without sending any request to the api